# Why state the Least Upper Bound Property again?

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, in section 1.8 he gives a definition of the supremum of a set $E$ which is bounded above.

But then he goes in section 1.10 to state the least-upper-bound property giving the same constraints on the set $E$ as in section 1.8, namely that $E \subset S$, $E$ is not empty and $E$ is bounded above, and then stating that the sup $E$ exists in $S$.

Don't we already know from 1.8 that the sup $E$ exists in $S$ if $E \subset S$, $E$ is not empty and $E$ is bounded above? Why state it again?

Comment: No. The set $\{q\in \mathbb{Q}: q^2<2\}$ doesn't have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$. That's what Rudin was trying to show with his example on the first page.

Comment: @QiyuWen, understood